# I want to be able to scroll a large image horizontally but at the same time show the entire height which can be variable

Tags: javascript, css

I have a large image 1900px by 1000px;  The width of it will be viewable by scrolling left and right via javascript as the overflow-x of the containing div is hidden. Image height will be scaled to show the full height of the image within the available space below a top banner down to the bottom of the viewport -- it will not require vertical scrolling.

My question is how best approach the scaling of the image height while still keeping the image proportions and still have the image large enough so that the horizontal scrolling still occurs (Unless screen resolution exceeds image proportions).  I'm hoping the answer can be done through CSS but a JavaScript solution is an option as well.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Slan

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;` which would allow native scrolling in the y direction only. You could then control the x scrolling via javascript.

Comment: I want the height of the image to always fill the screen neatly.  So the height of the image will always be viewable in its entirety but the width of it will be scrollable using javascript.  So only the overflow-x is set to hidden.